# I am uploading an image using PHP ,but its not uploading into folder?

Tags: php

I have checked php.ini File upload is On.
Below is the code Please Help me.
File is not uploading into the folder images.
I don't know what is the Problem with the code.
The problem is not in query , because **(!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"]))** not uploads the image.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                                     <th><input style=" width:100px; font-size:13px" name="op"  Placeholder="Operator Name"/></th>
 <th>  <input class="file-upload-input" type="file" name="uploadedimage"></th>

<th> <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="uploadnow" value="SUBMIT" class="theme-btn btn-style-one"></th>


                                    </tr></form>
                                <?php

    function GetImageExtension($imagetype)
     {
       if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
       switch($imagetype)
       {
           case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';
           case 'image/gif': return '.gif';
           case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';
           case 'image/png': return '.png';

           default: return false;
       }
     }

if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {

    $file_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"];
    $temp_name=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["tmp_name"];
    $imgtype=$_FILES["uploadedimage"]["type"];
    $ext= GetImageExtension($imgtype);
    $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;
    $target_path = "images/".$imagename;    
if($_POST['uploadnow'])
{
$op=$_POST['op'];
if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {
    $sql="INSERT INTO operator(op,mono) VALUES('".$op."','".$target_path."') ";
    mysql_query($sql) or die
    ("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysql_error());  
    }
}

?> <script type="text/javascript">
document.location.href='operator.php';
</script>
<?php

}
?>
```

Comment: Is the data being saved in db

Comment: your code seems correct..check the folder permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `$target_path = "/images/".$imagename;`

Comment: I check but not working , can you please recheck the code

Comment: The code looks legit, try to debug. Try echo "join" in that if (!empty($_FILES["uploadedimage"]["name"])) {

Answer (score 0):

Try putting these lines at the top of your code to show all PHP errors/warnings and see what you get.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```